# CodeIgniter jQueryUI dialog form example

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, jquery-ui-dialog

I am trying to use CodeIgniter and jQuery-ui dialog to create a modal window with form to update user information.

The process should be like:
1. Press a button on a view page.
2. A modal window pops up.
3. Inside the window is a form that a user can fill.
4. If the user filled something before, the information should be shown in corresponding field
5. Click the update button on the modal window to save the changes to database.

Can anyone provide a good sample of this process?

I used ajax to pass the data but it didn't work when I was trying to update the data to the database. It would be nice if an example of how to pass data from ajax to php and how php handle that.

Thanks,
Milo

Comment: It would be very helpful if you would ellaborate on how precisely it didn't work, and show us some code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well the jquery bit for post(), get(), ajax() works the same in any measure you would normally use it.. key difference here is with CI you can't post directly to a file-name file-location due to how it handles the URI requests. That said your post URL would be the similar to how you would access a view file normally otherwise

ie: /viewName/functionName (how you've done it with controllers to view all along. post, get, ajax doesnt have to end in a extension. I wish I had a better example then this but I can't seem to find one at the moment..

```
url = '/home/specialFunction';
jQuery.get(url, function(data) {
   jQuery("#div2display").html(data);
});
```

in the case of the above you notice despite it not being a great example that. you have the url with 2 parameters home and specialFunction

home in this case is the controller file for home in the control folder for the home file in views the specialFunction is a "public function" within the class that makes the home controller file. similar to that of index() but a separate function all together. Best way I have found to handle it is through .post() and a callback output expected in JSON cause you can form an array of data on the php side json_encode it and echo out that json_encode and then work with that like you would any JSON output. or if your just expecting a sinlge output and not multiples echoing it out is fine but enough of the end run output thats for you to decide with what your comfortable doing currently. Hopefully all around though this gives you some clairity and hopefully it works out for you.